# VBA Scrape: Get href from Each html element

Tags: vba, web-scraping, attributes, href

The code below successfully loops through each element in the DOM and puts each element in an Excel sheet. (tagName, ID, className etc.)

My question, is:

**How can I scrape the tag attibutes (title, href etc.) for each element?
Specifically, for an "A" tag, how can I scrape the "href" attribute?**

```
Enum READYSTATE
    READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
    READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
    READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
    READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
    READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim RowNumber As Integer
Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate "www.somesite.com"

Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "Connecting..."
    DoEvents
Loop

Set html = ie.document

RowNumber = 1
For Each element In html.all
    Cells(RowNumber, "A").Value = element.tagName
    Cells(RowNumber, "B").Value = element.ID
    Cells(RowNumber, "C").Value = element.className
    Cells(RowNumber, "D").Value = element.innerHTML
    RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
Next element
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line before `RowNumber = RowNumber + 1`:

```
If (element.tagName = "A") Then Cells(RowNumber, "E").Value=element.getAttribute("href")
```